# How can I remove "As low as" in Magento 2.3.1, if all the prices of the variants are the same?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

How can I remove "As low as" if all the prices of the variants of the configurable product are the same? It doesn´t make sense to me to show "As low as" when all the colors and sizes are equally expensive. I have some products that have different prices for the sizes, so they are absolutely correct with the addition "As low as". Simply the ability to disable it at all with display:none is not my goal. Help really appreciated!